# c++ expected unqualified-id before 'else' and expected declaration before '}' token errors

Tags: c++

I've been trying for several minutes to find out where the problem is located but without any luck. When compiling I get these errors:

```
Compiling 'Hero' for 'Arduino Mega 2560 or Mega ADK'
Maze.cpp : expected unqualified-id before 'else'
Maze.cpp : expected unqualified-id before 'else'
Maze.cpp : expected unqualified-id before 'else'
Maze.cpp : expected declaration before '}' token
Error compiling
```

I've checked all the brackets several times and I'm getting a headache, please help me locating the error.

```
MazeElement Maze::GetElement(byte direction, int distance){
    if (direction == ON_SPOT)
    {
        return Field[PositionX][PositionY];
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (Facing == Maze::NORTH && direction == Maze::FRONT ||
            Facing == Maze::EAST && direction == Maze::LEFT ||
            Facing == Maze::SOUTH && direction == Maze::BACK ||
            Facing == Maze::WEST && direction == Maze::RIGHT)
        {
            if (PositionY-distance >= 0)
                return Field[PositionX][PositionY-distance];
        } 
        else if (Facing == Maze::EAST && direction == Maze::FRONT ||
            Facing == Maze::SOUTH && direction == Maze::LEFT ||
            Facing == Maze::WEST && direction == Maze::BACK ||
            Facing == Maze::NORTH && direction == Maze::RIGHT)
        {
            if (PositionX+distance < sizeof(Field))
                return Field[PositionX+distance][PositionY];
        } 
        else if (Facing == Maze::SOUTH && direction == Maze::FRONT ||
            Facing == Maze::WEST && direction == Maze::LEFT ||
            Facing == Maze::NORTH && direction == Maze::BACK ||
            Facing == Maze::EAST && direction == Maze::RIGHT)
        {
            if (PositionY+distance < sizeof(Field[0]))
                return Field[PositionX][PositionY+distance];
        } 
        else if (Facing == Maze::WEST && direction == Maze::FRONT ||
            Facing == Maze::NORTH && direction == Maze::LEFT ||
            Facing == Maze::EAST && direction == Maze::BACK ||
            Facing == Maze::SOUTH && direction == Maze::RIGHT)
        {
            if (PositionX-distance >= 0)
                return Field[PositionX-distance][PositionY];
        } 
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but are you sure that `return NULL` will do the correct thing in this function? In C++ it's the same as `return 0`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. It turned out that the error came from a bracket not in this portion of code, but in a previous part of code. Yes, PositionX and PositionY are declared.
No, I'm not sure that returning NULL will do the correct thing. This shouldn't happen at all, and I don't know exceptions in c++.
Also, I have many other doubts about this language, but the question is solved for now.

Comment: C and C++ are are kind of known for presenting errors totally unrelated to the original error. For example, forgetting the termination semicolon of a structure/class definition in a header file can cause weird errors in the source files the header file is included in.